# subtract from one date another

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Good day. There is the following code that subtracts from one date another:

```vb
  Dim dt As New DateTime(2021, 8, 19)
        Dim dt2 As New DateTime(2022, 8, 29)
        MsgBox("Days Remaining : " & (dt2 - dt).Days)
```

tell me how to subtract format dates:
19.08.2021 14:07:16 - 24.08.2021 08:24:01

throwing away the time. I'm only interested in how to subtract dates of this format.
Date and time are entered in text boxes

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You would get the Date property ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date)) of the DateTime values. Also, I would probably recommend using DateTime.Subtract ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract)) which would return a TimeSpan value.

Take a look at this example:

```vb
Dim dt = New DateTime(2021, 8, 19)
Dim dt2 = New DateTime(2022, 8, 29)
Dim daysLeft = dt2.Subtract(dt).Days
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LMuWtu

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the formatted Dates then use .Date to keep only the Date part and throw away the time. Then you can substract and use TotalDays:

```
        Dim input1 As String = "19.08.2021 14:07:16"
        Dim input2 As String = "19.08.2021 14:07:16"

        Dim d1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(input1).Date
        Dim d2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(input1).Date

        Dim days As Single = (d1 - d2).TotalDays
```

The formatted dates should match your Culture format. You can also use Parse overload to use another Culture : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_